# How can I remove all special chars from UTF8 text in c#?

Tags: c#, regex, utf-8

I would like to remove all special characters from my UTF8 text, but I can't find any matching regular expression.

My text like this:

```
ASDÉÁPŐÓÖŰ_->,.!"%=%!HMHF
```

I would like to remove only these chars: `_->,.!"%=%!`

I tried this regex:

```
result = Regex.Replace(text, @"([^a-zA-Z0-9_]|^\s)", "");
```

But it removes my uft8 chars also.

I don't want to remove the accented characters, but I want to remove all glyph.

Comment: Define "special chars" please. Uncode contains tens of thousands of characters that are categorised: stating which categories you want to keep would be a start (and "utf8 char" has no meaning, UTF-8 is merely an encoding of Unicode code points into an octet stream, it says nothing about character taxonomy).

Comment: `\P{L}` should match anything NOT a *letter*.

Comment: I dont think it's duplicate. I dont need to determine if it contains utf-8 or not. I want to remove all glyph and others from an utf8 string. I don't want to remove the accented characters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"([^\w]|_)", "")
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. It removes all non numeric and non alphabet chars and it keeps my utf8 chars like this one: É ...

Comment: @tixovoxi Could you please accept the answer if it resolves your issue?

Comment: I have to wait 4 minutes it says.. :D

Answer (score 0):

you want only numbers and letters?

then this is your solution:

```
result = Regex.Replace(text, "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "");
```

you could also try to specify a range in the ASCII table if you want a custom way of things stay in your string:

```
result = Regex.Replace(text, "[^\x00-\x80]+", "");
```

Comment: This is a letter too: ú

Comment: this are just samples, you can edit it on your needs!